# Why would i want to store apscheduler jobs to JobStore (Redis, Mongo, etc.)?

Tags: python, mongodb, redis, jobs, apscheduler

The title is my question. I can't think of anything that is useful to store jobs to external database.

Can you guys provide some use cases?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you schedule jobs dynamically (at run time instead of adding them all at application startup), you don't want to lose them when you restart the application.

One such example would be scheduling notification emails to be sent, in response to user actions.

Comment: For persistence.@AhmetK